# Determine the domain-sets of $ Log(e^z-e^{-z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, principal-ideal-domains

Determine the domain-sets of $$ Log(e^z-e^{-z})$$

I only know that $e^z-e^{-z} > 0$ and so z must be positive. Also, $e^z = e^{x+iy} $

> The solution is $\Bbb{C}$ \ { $k \pi i | k \in \Bbb{Z}$ }

I don't understand the steps that will lead to this. Is there some other theory that I should know? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think a more relevant inferred condition is $e^z\neq e^{-z}$.  Does this help make the solution more clear?  Do you know what happens with $e^z$ when $z= ki\pi$?

Comment: it becomes (-1)^k, i think it get it now thanks!